# Centralizing libraries in julia

Tags: julia

I've long thought about learing [julia](http://julialang.org/) - a language I secretly hope will become the new standard for scientific computing - and when it is now packaged and included in the standard Ubuntu repositories, I figured it was time. I quickly found [this tutorial](http://forio.com/julia/tutorials/intermediate/tutorial1.html) and started hacking...

In the linked chapter, one is urged to download a library called `ols.jl` from a [Github repository](https://github.com/forio/ols.jl), place it in the local directory and start using it. I feel there must be a better way of doing this.

For example, it would be logical to have some "default"-directory in which julia can always look for library files. That folder could reside under my home directory, or (perhaps even better) somewhere under e.g. `/usr/share/lib` on an Ubuntu system.

Also, downloading the libraries directly seems to me like something I should be able to avoid. Isn't it possible to find libraries like these in some sort of packaging system (be it via Ubuntu's `apt-get` or something else)?

I do realize that many of these questions and concerns may be just because julia is a young language, that most of these features are missing because of this, and that there are plans (or at least wishes) to go in this direction in the future. However, it would be nice to know if I'm just missing something obvious =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial on Forio is ancient. There's a newer, much better package system as of version 0.1 of Julia. See the documentation here: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.1/manual/packages/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Tomas. We've updated the tutorial to use Julia's built-in linreg function. We'll follow up with a short tutorial on packages soon. It's amazing how quickly the language has moved. Those tutorials are less than a year old!